# Updating Google Form Drop down values on load

Tags: google-apps-script, google-forms

Is there anyway to update drop-down values of some Google Form items when users are loading the form? I know `onOpen` is just for openning the form in edit mode, but Just wanted to be sure weather is any workaround for this or not? if so, What would be then the alternatives? Using web form for instance, which is totally different approach maybe!?

Thanks,
M

Comment: In order to correctly understand about your question, can I ask you about the issue when you use the OnOpen event trigger?

Comment: @Tanaike onOpen is just for the edit mode as per documentation. I found the building the dropdown option will work.